# How to display monthly data in Highcharts graph?

Tags: datetime, highcharts, format, axis

Looks like a dumb question. And probably is. But I don't really get it.

I have monthly data over a ~30-year-period. I am neither sure how to format the data, nor am I sure how to format the Highcharts graph.

What is the correct way of data formatting? Like a "running month", from 1 to 433 (and more):

```
Date,Value
1,338.45
2,339.15
3,339.47
```

or in Date.UTC format:

```
Date,Value
Date.UTC(1980,1,1),338.45
Date.UTC(1980,2,1),339.15
Date.UTC(1980,3,1),339.47
```

I've done something similar like this, but don't think this is a good style:

```
Date,Value
1 Jan 1993,
2 Jan 1993,
3 Jan 1993,
4 Jan 1993,
5 Jan 1993,-4.19413878126
6 Jan 1993,
7 Jan 1993,
```

For the xAxis definition I've see different parameters being used. But as this depends on the data format, not quite sure what to put there:

```
xAxis: {
  type:"datetime",
  min: Date.UTC(1980, 1, 1),
  ...
```

Thanks a lot for any hints in which direction I should go.

Comment: I am sorry, can I ask what '338.45' is in 'Date.UTC(1980,1,1),338.45'?

Comment: I added title columns to the data, so it's perhaps more clear what I mean. Sorry. First column is always the date, second column is the data.

Comment: you can send the date in milliseconds. So '1 Jan 1993' is 725864400000. So send data to highcharts in the format 'dateInMilliSeconds,value'

Comment: Highcharts will accept the Date.UTC() format, as in your example, and also epoch time in milliseconds. You'll send the data as an array of arrays, ie: data:[[date, value],[date,value]...] etc For xAxis type, use 'datetime', as in your example. You don't need to worry about a min or max unless you have a specific reason to - the chart will figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A piece of advice, as you asked:

1. `Date.UTC(1980,1,1)` - this is JavaScript function, to return **timestamp**. For example `Date.UTC(1980,1,1)` -> `318211200000`. I suggest to use timestamp already in your data incoming for a chart. **Note:** Months in JS starts at 0 (0-> Jan, 1->Feb etc.).
2. `min: Date.UTC(1980, 1, 1)` -> this is not necessary, Highcharts lib is smart enough to calculate extremes on the xAxis, you don't have to set it, unless you want to display only part of the data on the chart.

And for example, I would use that format:

```
Date,Value
318211200000,338.45
320716800000,339.15
323395200000,339.47
```

Note that all formats are fine - I just suggest to use the easiest one ;)

Comment: I would also add to use date of something other than the first day of the month. You might get surprises on viewing the data in different time zones. For monthly data we set it as being on the 15th just in case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful. However, I'd really like to use the Y-M-D format, as I find it much more readable/understandable for the data reading (in the CSV file). [The fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/102n2er6/) works fine, but [my application](http://geodev.grid.unep.ch/mod_test/graph_co2_concentration.php) throws a #14 error. Any tip why that would be?

Comment: As I said: `Date.UTC()` is JavaScript function, so don't use this in the CSV file. If you prefer Y-M-D format, then use it directly in the CSV: `Date.UTC(1980,1,1)` -> `1980-02-01`. But please, don't forget to change Y-M-D format to timestamp in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

to set up teh xAxis as a time period you have these options:
1. using Date.UTC(Year, Month, Day):

```
data: [
  [Date.UTC(2016, 0, 5), 4],
  [Date.UTC(2016, 1, 6), 6],
  [Date.UTC(2016, 1, 7), 9],
```

check [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/9hk5scwu/)

2. using Dates written as numbers, specifies the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00.

   var xArr = [1455661712000,
       1455661791000,
       1455661869000,
       1455661947000,
     ];

Check [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/shecz3yp/)

I hope these help, otherwise feel free to ask for more details.